# Extending native focus() event to run a check, but only when anonymous function is not passed

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-events, modernizr

Working on a site that has multiple `focus()` events spread throughout maybe a dozen js files that all handle giving focus to the first text input on the page (ie: on the login page the email field is given focus automatically). I'd like to disable this feature for all touch devices.

We're already using Modernizr, so I can just check for the `.no-touch` class on the HTML tag to see if the user is on a touch device. However, in the interest of avoiding duplicate code and making this future proof (so we don't have to remember to check every time we add a new focus event) I'd like to just extend the native focus event to check for the `.no-touch` class and only proceed when that class exists.

How would I extend the native `focus()` event so that it checks the HTML tag for the `.no-touch` class and continues when it is present, but ONLY runs this check when an anonymous function is not passed to the `focus()` event?

For instance, there are occasions when we use focus with anonymous functions and I DON'T need to check for `.no-touch`, like this:

```
$("#login-email-address").focus(function(){ ... });
```

Make sense? If not, let me know how I can clarify...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
(function($,M){
    var nFocus = $.fn.focus;
    $.fn.focus = function(f){
        if(M.touch && !f)return this;
        return nFocus.apply(this,arguments);
    }
})(jQuery, Modernizer);
```

Comment: I must say that i strongly recommend that you NOT do this. but it's your code, do with it as you please.